# How can i know the url needed for my Get request

Tags: node.js, url, woocommerce, postman

I'm trying to do a GET request to this endpoint `/wp-json/wc/v3/products` to test my WooCommerce API connection using POSTMAN but I am getting a `404` error. Also I'm working on `localhost` and my wordpress is running on port 8000. So my url would be `localhost:8000/wp-json/wc/v3/products`. But as I told earlier, I am getting `404` status code.

[image: running server]

[image: 404 not found]

Thanks to the error code I know that it isnt the correct url, because it find no files, but I dont know what the correct url might be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access the api endpoint using the base url of your UI . The url you have provided is trying to find a html page in the specified url  path but as there is no front page served on that path you gets 404.

If you want to do a call to API instead , you have to find the api url. To know the API url you can use browser dev tool (  By clicking right mouse button and clicking inspect) .

Now navigate to network tab , and see what api backend calls the UI is making and use those urls in postman instead of the one you are trying now:

An example :

Here i am checking the backend call made by stack over flow , and retrieving the url

[image]